# How to run st_difference for complete table?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have 2 postGIS tables CITIES and WATERBODIES, I want to remove waterbody geometry from cities, I'm trying to use

```
CREATE TABLE usa_No_water_100 AS
SELECT ST_Difference(usa_100.geom, water_100.geom) AS geom
FROM usa_100, water_100
```

but this creates a table with 10000 entries, I'm looking for the same 100 rows which I have in cities shape but with waterbodies geometry subtracted.

Geometry layer is as follows
[image]
Water layer is as follows
[image]

I want to remove the cities shape which is under the water shape, so that geometry will be reduced
PS: I'm open to doing this via python as well, if you have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can to compare the geometries of `usa_100` with `water_100` table using [`ST_Difference`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html) as you suggested, but to avoid getting the product of both tables you have to put one in a subquery or [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/queries-with.html), e.g.

```
WITH j (geom) AS (
 SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM water_100
) SELECT ST_Difference(usa_100.geom,j.geom)
FROM usa_100,j
```

**Not**e: keep in mind what the `ST_Difference` documentation says:

> If A is completely contained in B then an empty geometry is returned.

So, if a polygon on `usa_100` entirely lies on a the result of `ST_Union` of `water_100`, it will return an empty geometry. If they do not spatially overlap, you do not have to worry about it.

Comment: I don;t think I have duplicate geom, basically the waterbodies are rivers and lakes and cities are the polygons, I want to remove the cities geometry which is under those waterbodies

Comment: @krishnalodha I see, you didn't state that in your question. Could you provide a small data sample and the expected results?

Comment: @krishnalodha can you try my last edit and tell me if it works?

Comment: using st_interesect will return boolean, which if true will push usa_100 geom as it is, we have to push the difference between geom :/ sorry but I'm confused

Comment: @krishnalodha I'm confused too :D but we can figure it out :) perhaps ST_Intersection is what you're looking for. Can you try this? `SELECT ST_Intersection(usa_100.geom,water_100.geom)
FROM usa_100
LEFT JOIN water_100 ON ST_Intersects(usa_100.geom,water_100.geom)`?

Comment: It returned null results, which means that the usa_100 and water_100 are not intersecting each other, well in that case we should have gotten the original usa_100 geom right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233403/discussion-between-jim-jones-and-krishna-lodha).